# Regular expression to remove numbers ending with "%" in python

Tags: python, regex

Quick question, how do I use regular expression or any method for that matter to remove every numeric value ending with the % sign from the list below. If similar question has been previously asked, kindly post the link, no need to down vote the question.
Thanks

```
my_list =  [['First Class', 'F, U', '150%'], ['P', '125%'], 
['Business Class', 'J, C, D, I', '125%'],
['Premium Economy Class', 'W', '110%'], 
['Economy Class', 'Y, B', '100%'], 
['E, H, M', '75%'], 
['L, N, R, S, V, K', '50%'], 
['T', '30%'], 
['Not eligible for accrual', 'Z, Q, G', '0%']]
```

Comment: Hmm, wonder if you actually tried something on your own yet? And exactly why do you want to use regex?

Comment: Well, the regular expression could be `^\d+%$`

Comment: I tried something on my own, it works but the words are broken up into letters which sucks

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a normal `list comprehension` and test every element of the sublists with `endswith()`.

```
new_list = [[i for i in l if not i.endswith('%')] for l in my_list]   
print(new_list)
```

gives

```
[['First Class', 'F, U'], ['P'], ['Business Class', 'J, C, D, I'], ['Premium Economy Class', 'W'], ['Economy Class', 'Y, B'], ['E, H, M'], ['L, N, R, S, V, K'], ['T'], ['Not eligible for accrual', 'Z, Q, G']]
```

Comment: Thank you . Better than using regular expressions